# I don't understand why the question about an eagle and a young goat is off-topic

Tags: discussion

Why is the question about an [eagle carrying off a young goat to its nest](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/24567/eagles-carrying-off-a-goat-to-its-nest-how-heavy-is-the-young-goat-how-strong) off-topic?

If the question had been about an eagle carrying off a small child from a campsite, or a small dog from a trail, would it have been off topic?

I find it hard to imagine how any question about the behavior of an eagle in the wild could be off topic.

Despite my disagreement, glad to see you back, Rory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that post is that it isn't really a simple/single question about an eagle and a goat - it asks a few questions which are either not obviously outdoors related, are cross posted, or are opinion.

- How heavy is the young goat
- How strong is the eagle

and so on.

If the question was "How much can an eagle carry?" that seems perfectly reasonable. "How heavy are young goats?" also maybe okay. But the post rambles around a few questions and settles on none that are relevant here - the cross post over on Biology seems better for all of them, I think.

You are typically very adept at improving questions so if you think you can limit it to something that is within our scope that would be superb.

Comment: +1, I am **NOT** voting to re-open the question for all the reasons posted here.

Comment: African or European eagle?